# Add JSON data fields names Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have data with no field names, I would like to append to each row a field name

```
[
    "James Vega",
    "23",
    "abc@test.com"
],
```

I want to add the fields to this JSON data, I'm working on Angular 6

```
[
    { "name": "James Vega" },
    { "Age": 23 },
    { "email": "abc@test.com" }
],
```

Comment: So is this an array with arrays..? And every inner array always has those 3 entries in the same order? And as result, why not a single object with all 3 keys..?

Answer (score 0):

You just use map function to transform the object you want

```js
let arr=
[
  [
      "James Vega",
      "23",
      "abc@test.com"
  ]
];

let arr_transform=arr.map(el=> ({
  name:el[0],
  age:el[1],
  email:el[2]
}));

console.log(arr_transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your order of property would be the same, then it is possible to create a mapping and map it with `O(1)`:

```js
const foo = [
    "James Vega",
    "23",
    "abc@test.com"
];
const mapping = {0: 'name', 1: 'Age', 2: 'email'};

const result = foo.map((el, i) => ({[mapping[i]]: el}));

console.log(result);
```